# How do I stream Linux audio to Mac computer?

Tags: audio, unix

Basically the reverse of this question:
[How do I stream Mac audio to Linux computer?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7236/how-do-i-stream-mac-audio-to-linux-computer)

How do I stream my linux audio (PopOS) to my Mac